# Empty connections to httpd create steady incoming traffic

Tags: centos, security, http, httpd

I noticed something weird in our server telemetry today where it showed that one of our servers is having a very steady incoming amount of traffic where it normally is very irregular.

When examining the apache server status it shows the following logs: (url replaced by example.com)

```
Srv PID Acc M   CPU SS  Req Conn    Child   Slot    Client  VHost   Request
1-0 3438    0/1/6295    _   0.01    7   29  0.0 0.00    211.21  [CLIENT IP] example.com:443 NULL
2-0 3439    0/4/6901    _   0.03    0   1   0.0 0.06    248.54  [CLIENT IP] example.com:443 NULL
```

There is a lot of requests coming in where the request parameter is `NULL` where on other requests the request is some form of the following: `GET / HTTP/1.0`

Could these connection attempts be malicious? I can't figure out what kind of purpose these would serve to an attacker. It doesn't even come close to the server it's capacity just a steady 5 mbps incoming traffic stream.